# .shop-domain shortcut doesn't work on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, url, safari

If I want to open the URL `http://amazon.shop` I usually type just `amazon.shop` (or `www.amazon.shop`) into my browsers adress bar (I know I could just open https://www.amazon.com, but the domain extension ".shop" is the important thing here). This works everywhere **except for Safari on iOS**, where it just performs a google-search for "amazon.shop". Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this?

Apple needs to code it. New TLDs come up all the time and some organizations [poke Apple with a stick](http://www.thedomains.com/2014/06/18/dna-asks-apple-to-recognize-new-gtlds-in-its-safari-browser-apple-id-apple-devices/) to make it happen.